# triangulation of a compact surface $v \leq f$

Tags: algebraic-topology

For any triangulation of a compact surface, show that

$$v \leq f$$

where $v,e,f$ is vertices, edges and triangle respectively.

Since each triangle has 3 edges and each edge is the common edge of exactly two triangles, we get $3f=2e$ and $v-e+f= \chi$. Hence $v=\dfrac{1}{2}f+\chi$ but i can't continue to indicate $f \geq v$

Comment: Shouldn't it be $v=\dfrac12\,f+\chi$?  Then, maybe, you could try to prove that any triangulation yields $f\geq 2\chi$ instead.

Comment: However, it may be very helpful to know that $\chi\leq 2$.  There is a bit of a problem.  There exists a triangulation of the sphere ($\chi=2$) with two triangles whose boundaries coincide.   This give $v=3$, $e=3$, and $f=2$.  This is the only case that violates $v\le f$.

Comment: oh, thank you. Should I claim that $f \geq 4$? Could you give me more detail?

Comment: You don't need to claim $f\geq 4$.  For a nonspherical compact surface, $\chi\leq 1$ (see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Surface_(topology)#Classification_of_closed_surfaces)), so you need $f\geq 2$, which is obvious.  For a sphere, you just have to exclude the case $f=2$ since the inequality is false.  Other cases work fine.  (Since $f$ is even for a sphere, we end up with $f\ge 4$ anyhow.)

Comment: oh, thank you @Batominovski